# encoding string in bits, 2 questions

Tags: c#, string, encoding, char, bit

I am writing a program. Actually the core function is working well, but I would like to upgrade it. My problem is around encoding and conversion on the way between string and bit values.

First I split string into array of int values by

```
    int[] bitValuesOfText = new int[Text.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
        bitValuesOfText[i] = (int)Text[i];
```

Then I split all of the values in the array into boolean values list (in the manner that if appropriate position of byte contain 1 then I add true, 0 otherwise). Then I am doing further things with such a list of bools.

The problem starts if I want to converse back the bits into string. Then weird letters like ä, ę, à etc dissapear.

On the reverse way I am just adding each 8 bits (of course each bit make to the appropriate power; i iterate for each bits).

```
value += Int32.Parse(Math.Pow(2, (7 - (i % 8))).ToString());
```

And every 8 bits I am doing

```
string += (char)value
```

I know that I have to use some kind of encoding, and I tried to do with some examples but without success. Should I use utf8 or unicode and in which moment exactly ? Just in reverse way or before both conversions ?

Also I consider to change it into byte type, but I plan to do so after this problematic issue.

Comment: `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string)` returns a byte array for the particular string. Likewise there is a `GetString(byte[])` method that returns the string from a byte array (and same kinds of functions for different encodings). I'm guessing what you are trying to get at is some kind of string compression, but assuming each character is 4 bytes (int) instead of 7 bits, 8 bits, etc is actually more like inflation than compression. Booleans also take up more than one bit in memory or a file, so it depends on how you are storing them, either way its a lot bigger.

Comment: I am doing program used to stegeanography rather than compression.
Thanks for suggestions. I am trying to fix it in such a way, but without succes too. 
Right now I have discovered that majority of characters give the byte value 254, no matter which one of them it is. This means that I have to work also with encoding at the first stage as well.
More comments and suggestions would be welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When talking about converting between bytes and characters, you need to think about encodings. There is no "default" way to encode characters using bytes, but when you force the issue by using a cast, the .NET framework does a very crude UTF-16 conversion. In .NET programs you should invoke an `Encoding` object if you want to get a predictable conversion to or from bytes.

It's *very* important that you use the same type of encoding to write and read the bytes. If you try to read characters written with a different encoding, you will find it often works, but fails in some scenarios. Whenever you see the � character in a web-page, that's where it failed to decode the character specified because the browser used a different encoding from the one that was used to encode it.

In order to use an `Encoding`, ideally you should be working with a stream of `byte` values, so that an encoding can use multiple bytes to represent a single character. If you don't need to represent a large range of glyphs, you can possibly use a very simple encoding like ASCII, but a more complete solution is to use a Unicode encoding (e.g. UTF-8) to enable a much more reasonable range.

You may find [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by [Joel Spolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) to be a very informative (and entertaining) read into this topic.

It's hard to offer more specific advice without knowing the problem domain better, but I would be trying to create an implementation of `Stream` which allowed the reading and writing of bytes using your stegeanographic techniques. This avoids the issues of the encoding of data, so you can focus on just reading and writing the raw byte values.

If you can read and write a stream of bytes, you can use it with a very large number of .NET classes; almost all serialization, storage and network components work on a `Stream` at some level.

Comment: Thank you for response, it gave me useful information.
Finally I did it work, I changed ints to bytes and I work with Encoding.UTF8 in both cases, encoding and decoding. I will investigate issue about Stream after I finish the primary aims of this project. 
Thank you for the link and I wish you nice day as well the night.

Comment: A cast from `char` to `int` is lossless and preserves the UTF-16 encoding inherent in a .NET string. Nothing at all to do with ASCII.